# extract text between delimiters in c

Tags: c, string

What I'm looking for is basically equivalent to extracting the text between parentheses, and that's the example I'll use. If my input is something like `(test 1 2)(test 3 4)test foo bar(test again)` the code below returns exactly what I want:

```
token: test 1 2
token: test 3 4
token: test again
```

But if my input is `(test 1 (test 2 3)foo(bar test) again)` I get

```
token: test 1 
token: test 2 3
token: bar test
```

I don't want to see `test 1`. Yes, it's between a left paren and right paren, but it means something went wrong further upstream from this bit of data.

```
void print_tokens(char *s) {
    printf("input: %s\n",s);
    char *output;
    const char *valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ";
    unsigned int length;
    s=strchr(s,'(')+1;
    length=strspn(s,valid);
    while(s!=NULL && length>0) {
        output=malloc(length+1);
        strncpy(output,s,length);
        output[length]='\0';
        printf("token: %s\n",output);
        free(output);
        if(strchr(s,'(')!=NULL) {
            s=strchr(s,'(')+1;
            length=strspn(s,valid);
        } else {
            s=NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Aside from being rather loose with the memory management, this slap-dash approach might be "close enough" as I have another function (to which the output will actually get passed that does some checking on its own input, but this could still let some malformed expressions through, and I'd like to avoid that if possible. Though what I'm looking for could be easily summarized in a regular expression (`/.*\(([a-z0-9 ]*?)\)/` I believe), it has to be in more-or-less standard C. GNU C, Boost, and most of the other libraries I've seen that help with string parsing or regexes aren't available to me.

Is there some better way to pull out this text that will eliminate the extraneous token? And be more flexible with the valid character set (for instance, everything *except* left and right parentheses)?

Comment: So, to be clear, the correct output for this function is only what's *directly* in between parenthesis? Also, does the order of their output matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just about do it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_tokens(char *s)
{
    printf("input: %s\n", s);
    char *start = s;
    char *end = s;
    while(*s) {
        if(*s == '(') start = s;
        else if(*s == ')') end = s;
        if(start < end && *start) {
              *end = 0;
              printf("token: %s\n", start+1);
              start = s = end;
        }
        s++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "(test 1 (test 2 3)foo(bar test) again)";
    char str2[] = "(test 1 2)(test 3 4)test foo bar(test again)";
    print_tokens(str);
    print_tokens(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

It works on both of the test cases you gave me. Note that it clobbers the original string, so you should add some code to duplicate the string if you don't want it to do that.

Comment: Both of the posted methods work (the first with a few tweaks), but the second one, sans the string copy which as you mentioned, I won't need, will work beautifully! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Crappy pseudo-code:

```
  char *c = start;
  char *d;

  while (*c) {
    while (*c && *c != '(') c++;
    /* we found a left paren */
    d = ++c;
    while (*d && *d != ')') {
      if (*d == '(') {
        /* reset! */
        c = d;
        break;
      }
      if (*d == ')') {
        *d = 0;
        printf("token: %s\n", c);
        c = d;
        continue;
      }
      d++
    }
  }
  printf("finished\n");
```

Comment: Change the first `continue` to a `break` and add a `d++` to the while loop and it does the trick.